# PHP Deleting images

Tags: php

I have an admin system which adds profile pages dynamically - and part of that adds images to a directory. When I add the images they all have the name format like 12_1.jpg, 12_2.jpg, 32_1.jpg, 32_9.jpg where the number before the underscore is the id `$cid` and the number after the underscore is the image number.

I'm trying to find a way to list the images on the edit-images.php page with an option to delete them (maybe a link next to the image name, or another way that is better).

Here is the code to find the images I need to have the option of deleting:

```
if ($handle = opendir('../images/company')) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {      
      if (substr(basename($entry), 0, 2) == $cid) {
        echo $entry . "<br>";
      }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

How would I go about deleting specified images from here? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You would ask which one they wanted to delete then delete the appropriate file making sure that it was one of the files you expected. If you try that and get stuck, show us where you got to and we will help out.

Comment: `$cid` is the id number for the profile page

Comment: @Anigel thanks for your response, I will give this a go and let you know if I get stuck! I know what I want to achieve I'm just having problems implementing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you scanning the directory for the file? You can check if the file exists and delete it instead. For example:

```
$files = glob("../images/company/$cid_*.jpg");
foreach($files as $file) {
  if(file_exists($file)) unlink($file);
}
```

This will unlink all files in `../images/company` with the name starting with `123_` for example and ending in `.jpg` (you can provide more extensions by using `GLOB_BRACE` parameter)

Comment: If I used `$files = glob("../images/company/$cid_*");` would that delete all images so if some where gif, png example it would delete them too?

Comment: Yes, it would delete all files with anything after `123_` in the name, for example.

Answer (score 2):

In php you use the [unlink](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) function to delete files. Just echo a link to a page that calls a function do to that and pass the image name. Only be sure to check the user input before actually perform deletion.

Comment: I wasn't very clear. Ideally I would like to list all the images associated with a profile page (say 9 images for example) and then have an option to delete them one at a time, staying on the same page if possible?

Comment: Yes, there are two ways: 1. use Ajax to call another page "in the background" and then remove the image from display via javascript or 2: put a link like this yourpage.php?action=deleteimage&img=$imagename and then check the action via $_GET, perform the deletion and re-render the page.

Comment: Cheers. I think I will give option 2 ago! Thanks for your help.